# I would like my page to look the same in all browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

How can I make this CSS work in IE 8?

I use this to call from my html docs (no repeat coding that way - saves space):

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
@import url("default.css");
-->
</style>
```

And here's what "default.css" looks like:

```
body {
    background-image: url(/images/31.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: #000;
    background-position: center;
}
body,td,th {
    font-family: Trebuchet MS, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #F0F;
    font-size: 22;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000, -2px -2px 2px #000, -2px 2px 2px #000, 2px -2px 2px #000;
}
a:link {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000, -2px -2px 2px #000, -2px 2px 2px #000, 2px -2px 2px #000;
}
a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000, -2px -2px 2px #000, -2px 2px 2px #000, 2px -2px 2px #000;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline, bold;
    color: #FFF;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #F0F, -2px -2px 2px #F0F, -2px 2px 2px #F0F, 2px -2px 2px #F0F;
}
a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #F0F, -2px -2px 2px #F0F, -2px 2px 2px #F0F, 2px -2px 2px #F0F;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-family: Trebuchet MS, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000, -2px -2px 2px #000, -2px 2px 2px #000, 2px -2px 2px #000;
}
```

It looks lovely in Firefox, but it doesn't render up so nicely in Explorer, and that's REALLY irritating because I prefer uniformity!

Is there something I can do? I understand not many people would still be using older versions of IE, but some still do (like XP users).

Comment: http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Comment: Personally, I don't think you should encourage people to use old versions of IE. That said, [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=list+of+IE's+css+problems) might help.

Comment: If you have a specific question about a specific issue, please ask that in detail.  Just posting all of your css and asking how to make it work in IE is not a very good question.

Comment: Addressing the numerous CSS differences between browsers in a single question is not possible.  That being said, you should start out with a good CSS reset to eliminate browser-specific default stylings.

Comment: Yes, my problem was essentially with text-shadow. Since that's obviously not going to work, I will just leave it as-is and suggest a browser upgrade for users who can't see what they're supposed to. Much easier than trying to write another hundred lines of IE support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When designing for older browsers you need to make sure that it supports the specific feature you are trying to implement. There isn't much to work with from what you have posted but you are most likely not getting the text-shadow you desire. IE 8 doesn't support text-shadow (http://caniuse.com/#search=text-shadow).

Use the website above to check for feature support. Goodluck.